# Conditional view within views of state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We have a `main` state consisting of a main container, header and footer.

```
.state('main', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/main/main_view.html'
      },
      'topnavbar@main': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/topnavbar/topnavbar_view.html',
        controller: 'TopNavBarController',
      },
      'footer@main': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/footer/footer_view.html'
      }
    }
  })
```

There is a conditional popup within `topnavbar_view.html` that should be showed/hidden when clicked. How can I toggle this state?

I could add this view to state `main`:

```
'usersettings@main': {
    templateUrl: 'modules/usersettings/view.html'
},
```

`topnavbar_view.html`: And toggle the view by setting boolean on `$scope.showUserSettings`

```
<div ng-show="showUserSettings">
    <div ui-view="usersettings"></div>
</div>
```

I guess there must be a more elegant way?

Comment: i would use directives inside template for such needs

Comment: What (and where) determines whether to show/hide the popup? And I'm not clear how adding another state helps. Perhaps, add more details about how this conditional statement is to be used

Comment: As I wrote, "And toggle the view by setting boolean on $scope.showUserSettings" , `TopNavBarController` will determine. I want to know if there is any better way of showing a partial within a view like `topnavbar@main`

Comment: @guramidev where do you store the state of showing/hiding for ng-show?

Comment: @Shlomo Goldstein you store it inside controller and pass it as a parameter to directive